# Why is HTTP version number presented in both a request line and a status line?

Tags: http, http-headers

I've researched a bit to find out that the Status line is the the start line of an HTTP response. It contains the information such as the protocol version, a status text, status code. But why does it have to contain the protocol version again?

Comment: mostly to verify the protocol. Non-http servers 9may respond to an HTTP message, likely with a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP version numbers are present in the request and response for HTTP/1.0 and 1.1. (HTTP/2 is quite different. When using a browser, the protocol is negotiated by the TLS connection wrapped around HTTP.)

[RFC 2145](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2145#section-2.3) says,

> An HTTP server SHOULD send a response version equal to the highest
> version for which the server is at least conditionally compliant, and
> whose major version is less than or equal to the one received in the
> request.  An HTTP server MUST NOT send a version for which it is not
> at least conditionally compliant.  A server MAY send a 505 (HTTP
> Version Not Supported) response if cannot send a response using the
> major version used in the client's request.

This means a server compatible with HTTP/1.1 should respond with HTTP/1.1 to both, HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/1.0 requests. A server supporting only HTTP/1.0, could respond to HTTP/1.1 request with HTTP/1.0 responses.

For example, if you send a HTTP/1.0 request to wikipedia.org,

```
$ nc wikipedia.org 80
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 400 
Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 18:03:20 GMT
Server: Varnish
...
```

the server responds with HTTP/1.1 (although with an error).

So the version number is also included in the response because it might be different from the one in the request.